# Appenchild is throwing an error when trying to append a modal to a div

Tags: javascript, django

I am currently exploring and trying to create a Django application. The problem I am facing currently is, while trying to append a modal to a div element in the HTML file, the JavaScript threw an error saying :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: modalContainer.appendChild is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.replyModal ((index):217:28)
```

Here is the code throwing the problem:

```
            console.log("REPLY MODAL");

            var modal = document.createElement('div');
            modal.className = "modal fade";
            modal.id = "reply-modal";
            modal.tabIndex = "-1";
            modal.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", "Reply to feedback");
            modal.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

            var modalDialog = document.createElement('div');
            modalDialog.className = "modal-dialog";
            
            var modalContent = document.createElement('div');
            modalContent.className = "modal-content";

            var modalHeader = document.createElement('div');
            modalHeader.className = "modal-header";

            var modalTitle = document.createElement('h5');
            modalTitle.className = "modal-title";
            modalTitle.innerHTML = "Reply to feedback";

            var modalCloseButton = document.createElement('button');
            modalCloseButton.className = "btn-close";

            var modalBody = document.createElement('div');
            modalBody.className = "modal-body";

            var modalForm = document.createElement('form');
            modalForm.method = "POST";
            modalForm.action = "/suggestionbox/reply/" + feedback.pk + "/";
            modalForm.id = "reply-form";

            var modalCsrfToken = document.createElement('input');
            modalCsrfToken.type = "hidden";
            modalCsrfToken.name = "csrfmiddlewaretoken";

            var modalFormGroup = document.createElement('div');
            modalFormGroup.className = "form-group";

            var modalLabel = document.createElement('label');
            modalLabel.for = "reply";
            modalLabel.innerHTML = "Reply";

            var modalTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
            modalTextArea.className = "form-control";
            modalTextArea.id = "reply";

            var modalSubmitButton = document.createElement('button');
            modalSubmitButton.type = "submit";
            modalSubmitButton.className = "btn btn-primary";
            modalSubmitButton.innerHTML = "Submit";

            modalFormGroup.appendChild(modalLabel);
            modalFormGroup.appendChild(modalTextArea);
            modalForm.appendChild(modalCsrfToken);
            modalForm.appendChild(modalFormGroup);
            modalForm.appendChild(modalSubmitButton);
            modalBody.appendChild(modalForm);
            modalHeader.appendChild(modalTitle);
            modalHeader.appendChild(modalCloseButton);
            modalContent.appendChild(modalHeader);
            modalContent.appendChild(modalBody);
            modalDialog.appendChild(modalContent);
            modal.appendChild(modalDialog);
            modalContainer.appendChild(modal);


            var replyButton = document.getElementById("reply-button");
            replyButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var reply = document.getElementById("reply").value;
                var feedbackId = feedback.pk;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/suggestionbox/reply/" + feedbackId + "/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                        reply: reply
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("REPLY SUCCESSFUL");
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

I can't seem to find an answer relating to my problem. I hope you guys at the forum can help. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log(modalCointainer)` just before the line: `modalContainer.appendChild(modal);` ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I managed to fix it by changing the last AppendChild to :
$(".modal-container").append(replyModal); but now it throws a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'hidden' because of this line : replyModalCsrf.type = "hidden";, any idea why this is the case? and now my cards won't appear too